# Voltage doubler operation

Tags: ac, electricity, voltage-doubler

I searched the voltage doubler circuit and I understoond how it should operate but I don't understand something.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmHn4x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a voltage doubler: ( or at least what I have found).

[image]

In the first half-cycle D1 will be on and D2 will be off and in the second half-cycle D2 will be on and D1 will be off.

In the first quarter-cycle of the sine wave C1 will be charging to a voltage.However in the second-cycle quarter of the sine wave C2 will discharge through the source-> becoming uncharged.

When we go to the third quarter-cycle the C2 and C1 will be charging while in the fourth quarter-cycle C2 and C1 will be discharging through the source.

However for this circuit to be a voltage double C1 must remain charged with opposite polarity to the source's polarity in the third quarter-cycle so C2 becomes charged from the total voltage of those 2.

Any help?

Comment: What is the current path that you think C1 will discharge through? D1 won't be forward biased.

Comment: Ah yes you are correct thank you.